# Redirect after register in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, registration

I am using Laravel 5.

I wanted to redirect a user after a successful registration.  I have tried these in my authcontroller but it doesn't work.

```
protected $loginPath = '/plan';
protected $redirectTo = '/plan';
protected $redirectAfterRegister = 'plan/';
```

These work on successful login though but not after registration.

I have also tried `postRegister` to render a view but using a `postRegister` method overrides the registration process and I don't want to do that.  I just want to redirect the user to a page on successful registration.

Answer (score 8):

There are two options to specify where to redirect the user in the
**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

For a simple URL you can override this property.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

If you have a more complicated logic than just one static URL, since Laravel 5.3 you can add a method in the same class RegisterController, with name **redirectTo()**:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (auth()->user()->role_id == 1) {
        return '/admin';
    }
    return '/home';
}
```

The method behavior will override $redirectTo property value, even if the value is present.

Answer (score 6):

Overriding the postRegister function like you mention should work, you would do this in your `AuthController`:

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
 {
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));     
    // Now you can redirect!
    return redirect('/plan');
 }
```

Or something like it. Copy it from the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` that is used in the top of your `AuthController`, here you will find all the functions

For this to work your `AuthController` should use the 'AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' trait, which is there by default.

More info about redirects in case you want to redirect to a named route: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects

Comment: This really helped! This way you have more control. Just had to remove resgistrar though, since its removed in 5.1, So change $this->registrar->validator to $this->validator, same for create. If you have the validator and create in the same class that is.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add below line to AuthController class in Auth/AuthController.php

```
protected $redirectPath= '/plan';
```

Above redirect path will be used for successful login and successful register.

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify the return of register() in RegisterUsers.php:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
    // Originally the parameter is $this->redirectPath()
    return redirect()->to('/plans');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is laravel 5.4 solution

```
     /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {

          //User register now here you can run any code you want 
          if (\Request::ajax()){

            return response()->json([
                'auth' => auth()->check(),
                'intended' => $this->redirectPath(),
            ]);
            exit();
        }
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

keep in mind `register()` Handle a registration request for the application.
where `registered()` called when user created.

Answer (score 2):

after run command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

laravel create auth controller and resource files for change the route of register user
just go to below path

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController
```

and change the `protected $redirectTo` param
and you can user this way in `LoginController` next of `RegisterController`
for redirect after login