# how do i redirect register to antoher page?

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am already logged in to admin and I have a button called add user that takes me to the `auth/register.blade.php` file. I want to redirect the register back to the admin page where it displays all the users, it works but it doesn't register the user that I added, not in the DB. I really want to know what's wrong.
here's how I modified the register controller:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth
 /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
            return 'admin';
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

I need this for a project so I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect after register in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102564/redirect-after-register-in-laravel)

Comment: I saw this but I thought it wouldn't work since I'm using Laravel 8.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: It doesn't work because I'm using Laravel 8, and I don't have AuthController.

Comment: post your whole controller