# Redirect after registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am using laravel 5.5

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I want to change the redirect of a billing page to the dashboard after a successful registration. I have changed the
Protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
but it always take me to the billing page

I tried changing  the redirect to the dashboard but it wants the user to fill the billing form before they can access the dashboard.
I want the user to skip that billing process

Comment: This question already has answers here **redirect-after-register-in-laravel**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102564/redirect-after-register-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Look for `RegistersUsers.php` under the `yourproject\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\` folder and you can update the `registered` function to:

```
  protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect ('/dashboard')
    }
```